# Ubuntu does not recognize my cell phone

Tags: usb, android, samsung

My version of ubuntu is 18.04. My Samsung cell phone is running Android 5.1.1.

Two days ago I tried to connect my cell phone to Ubuntu and it did not recognize it. I read tutorials, but they were from outdated versions of Ubuntu and I got errors. Also Ubuntu did not have the 51-android.rules folder that I had to put it in.

Finally it recognized my USB memory, but only one of them.

It does not throw any error, only Ubuntu does not recognize it when I connect it, and neither does `lsusb`. I add that the cell phone begins to load but Ubuntu does not recognize it.

When I connect it by USB to the computer, Ubuntu recognizes my modem that I also connect with USB, but not the cell phone

Image of what it tells me when I run `lsusb` when my cell phone does not appear:

[image]

Comment: You should: 1. Say what version of Ubuntu 2. Show what errors you get as text. 3. Show what changes you made the `.rules` files. 4. Say exactly _how_ you are trying to connect your phone to Ubuntu. [Edit] the question and provide these details.

Comment: Your phone uses MTP to enable mounting it's internal memory in a USB connect PC. This has to be enabled in the phone itself. Connect the cable then go to the dropdown menu in your phone, tap USB connection and choose the proper option.

Comment: PROBLEM FIX, the cable is the error

Comment: @MiguelAngelMateo Do you mean there was a hardware problem and you had to replace the cable? Or do you mean that you had to follow [the procedure GabrielaGarcia gave](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115877/ubuntu-does-not-recognize-my-cell-phone/1169824#comment1843262_1115877) about how to make it work with the cable? I posted [that](https://askubuntu.com/a/1169824) but if I misunderstood and it was a hardware problem with a specific cable that went away when you replaced it, I'll delete that post. (In that case it would be correct for us to close this as "a problem that can't be reproduced")

Answer (score 2):

The solution was [given in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115877/ubuntu-does-not-recognize-my-cell-phone#comment1843262_1115877) by [GabrielaGarcia](https://askubuntu.com/users/880592/gabrielagarcia):

> Your phone uses MTP to enable mounting it's internal memory in a USB connect PC. This has to be enabled in the phone itself. Connect the cable then go to the dropdown menu in your phone, tap USB connection and choose the proper option.

– [GabrielaGarcia](https://askubuntu.com/users/880592/gabrielagarcia) [Feb 6 at 13:51](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115877/ubuntu-does-not-recognize-my-cell-phone#comment1843262_1115877)

Comment: I've [requested clarification](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115877/ubuntu-does-not-recognize-my-cell-phone/1169824#comment1952085_1115877) in case I've misunderstood and this is not what solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Install adb/fastboot utils included on the SDK light package. There are tutorials, it is a simple Konsole procedure. Then type adb devices. Your phone, rooted or not should have Developer tools activated by 7 touch method, and then android debugging active. Or, the way to access only the storage, you select what type of connection, on Developer Tools. If you want to transfer files or not. I really don't know, but keeping the SDK or only adb/fastboot package is always useful. I "compressed" a bit, but it is, using the simplified SDK tools, or choosing USB connection. Congrats

Comment: AFAIK these utilities are for advanced users. I'm not sure if this would really help someone who is new into these.

Answer (score 1):

This works often to connect to my cell phone

sudo service network-manager restart

Using Ubuntu 18.04 that starts a connection to my cell phone sometimes. If not then turn the wifi off airplane mode and then on again and sometimes it works. Or try this in your terminal:

dhcpcd wlp2s0bi

The interface on mine is wlp2s0bi. Using dhcpcd with that interface 
identifier also can connect to the cell phone. Use this to find your interface. Open terminal and put in iwconfig and your interface will show there.

This has also worked to start a connection to my cell phone.

nmcli networking off

And then

nmcli networking on

Just switching off and turning back on starts it sometimes. Good luck.